# How to change value of input:text when value of another input:text is changed without user interaction with the other input

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have two input[type=text]:

```
<input type=text id=inputOne>
<input type=text id=summary>
```

**I want to update `#summary.value` with `#inputOne.value` when `#inputOne` is changed (this is the question).** The problem I couldn't solve is *"user" is not accessing/changing `#inputOne` directly*, so its `blur`, `keyup`, `change`, `onmouseover` etc. events aren't firing up, or they're but I couldn't make it work.

The user changes `#inputOne.value` with `unknownFunction`, which I can not modify, nor access.

```
<script>
  ...
  unknownFunction(){
     ...
     $("#inputOne").val(aDynamicValue);
  }
</script>
```

The basic jQuery function I tried, is as follows. It's not working :)

```
<script>
   ...
   $("#inputOne").change(function(){
       $("#summary").val("Value: "+$(this).val()+"...");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It may not be safer but you could also use a `$.valHooks` to trigger a `change` event after updating the `input` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the function that's updating the value, you'll have to poll the source for changes.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var inputOne = $('#inputOne'), summary = $('#summary'), previous = $inputOne.val();
  return function() {
    var current = inputOne.val();
    if (current !== previous) {
      summary.val('Value: ' + current + '...');
      previous = current;
    }
  }
}(), 100);
```

That'll check the input every 100ms for a change, and update the summary when the value is updated.

Comment: @Turcia great! The day I type something in properly on the first try is the day I'll know I've been replaced by an android :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#common-event-behaviors), programmatically changing the value of an input element should trigger the `input` and `change` events.  The `input` event occurs when the contents of the element are changed, the `change` event occurs when the change is *committed*, e.g. tabbing out of the element.

This suggests that binding a handler for the `input` event should work better than `change`. Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks :)  `$("#inputOne").bind('input', function(){ ... });` (it's not working in my case, or my syntax is wrong)

Comment: Syntax looks right, I guess the spec isn't being followed yet.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on all browsers and Jquery <= v1.10

```
$('#inputOne').on('keyup', function () {
    $("#summary").val("Value: "+$(this).val()+"...");
});
```

Textbox input field change event fires as you would expect it to, the jQuery .Change event only works correctly on html5 supported browsers